# Why do multiple Kafka consumers consume at different speeds when they are grouped, versus not?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm consuming from a 24-partition topic using two consumers (Mirrormaker 1 instances, as distributed with Kafka v2.4.0) at the same time, each with 12 threads.

When I start one consumer, it consumes at ~140,000 messages per second.

When I start the second consumer, on a second machine, with the same group name, the first consumer slows down to 70,000 messages per second, and the second consumer consumes at 70,000 messages per second.

When I start the second consumer, on a second machine, with a different group name, they each consume at 140,000 messages per second.

The only quota set is a default one for clients, set to 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 (this is just set to allow JMX to report individual client speeds)

Why do I see different behavior here?

EDIT: While there are plenty of workarounds for this, including not using this software, this question is geared more towards explaining the behavior difference I see with two mirrormaker consumers, between when they are grouped versus non-grouped.

Comment: Why not MirrorMaker 2?

Comment: I'd like to figure out what is causing this behavior before trying something else, in case I see this behavior again sometime in the future and need to fix it.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that MirrorMaker depends on the older consumer API, and Kafka Connect uses the new one. So, I would maybe suggest trying at least console consumer (or kafkacat) of the same group, and not Mirroring.

Comment: There is also `kafka-consumer-perf-test` or `kafka-verifiable-consumer` that could be tested with

Comment: For both of those, their single-process performance exceeds the 2-clients-grouped performance, using a 2M-record payload file for the producer, and the same consumer and producer config files -- still trying to figure out the root cause though :(

Comment: You should be able to pass `--group` to at least one of those processes

Comment: It is passed to both -- even when consuming as the sole member of the group, they outperform both the single-node performance and the double-node performance of mirrormaker, but I cannot figure out the root cause of why the double-node performance of mirrormaker is the same as the single-node performance of it, except when they are not grouped. :(

Comment: Like I said, it could be the usage of the older consumer API